# 403 Forbidden error using Cloudfront signed cookies?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Very weird behaviour I am seeing.

I am using cloudfront signed cookies to give restricted access to a group of files in cloudfront. On most internet connections this works fine.
But on some others, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Is there anything specifically I can be looking at here? i.e. some behaviour by some internet connections that prevents cloudfront cookies from working. Nothing to do with the machine itself as my laptop will work fine on some wifi connections but not on others.

Any help would be great, as I am really at a loss with this one.

Update - It seems that it does not work when trying to access the files from IpV6 ip address. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: *"it does now work"* ... did you mean to say it does **not** work?  Are you using the `"IpAddress":{"AWS:SourceIp": ...}` policy condition?  (Because that condition supports IPv4 only...)

Comment: Hi @michael-sqlbot. Yep sorry that was a typo I meant to say "it does not work". So when using the Java SDK, I can't seem to find a way to not include  the "IpAddress" field in the custom policy. I even set it to "0.0.0.0/0" so all ip ranges have access. Any ideas?

Comment: That's interesting.  `0.0.0.0/0` is only all IPv4.  This seems like the root of your problem.  Show your code?

Comment: Ah I see! OK I can actually set the ip range to null. I will test that now.

Comment: Did that work as expected?

Comment: Yep sure did! Just had to set the ip address to null and it is working fine now. Thanks for the help Michael!

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed now!

I had to set the ip address to null in the code that defines custom policy and now it works fine for both IPv4 and IPv6 ip addresses. 0.0.0.0/0 only allows all IPv4 ip addresses access, since this feature doesn't support IPv6.

> IP addresses in IPv6 format, such as 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334, are not supported.
>
> If you're using a custom policy that includes `IpAddress`, do not enable IPv6 for the distribution.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-signature-cookies